# Kubernetes deployment of tomcat docker image needs custom server,xml

Tags: java, kubernetes, tomcat, dockerfile

When deploying the app, certain environment-specific settings need to be applied to the server.xml, which cannot be applied when the container is built. Has anyone tried using a volume_mounted config file, and where would I tell tomcat the location of this custom config?

Comment: it will certainly work. one another option is loading site specific values using config map as env variables, which can be used directly in server.xml file

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate [Nataraj Medayhal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19246531/nataraj-medayhal), you can find an example based on configMap on [`devlinx9/k8s_tomcat_custer`](https://github.com/devlinx9/k8s_tomcat_custer)

> The configMap is used to control the configuration of tomcat, in this we added the cluster configuration, save the following text in a file `configmap-tomcat.yaml`
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: v1
> kind: ConfigMap
> metadata:
>  name: testconfig
> data:
>  server.xml: |
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>
>    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
>      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
>
>      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
> ...
>    </Server>
> ```
>
> Create the configMap:
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f configmap-tomcat.yaml -n {namespace}
> ```